# Getting IP addresses from users using Python?

Tags: python, get, ip

I would like to know the right code in order to get the ip address from the user after visiting my website using Python. I've searched but nothing found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Missing information - Is the website hosted? Which server is running? The only way to get that info is in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are running Django? If so use this snippet(just call it in your view function):

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Comment: Okay how can I use it in order to get the ip?